# What libraries are available for parsing c++ to extract type information

Tags: c++, parsing, types

I'm looking for a way to parse c++ code to retrieve some basic information about classes. I don't actually need much information from the code itself, but I do need it to handle things like macros and templates. In short, I want to extract the "structure" of the code, what you would show in a UML diagram.

For each class/struct/union/enum/typedef in the code base, all I need (after templates & macros have been handled) is:

- Their name
- The namespace in which they live
- The fields contained within (name of type, name of field and access restrictions, such as private/mutable/etc)
- Functions contained within (return type, name, parameters)
- The declaring file
- Line/column numbers (or byte offset in file) where the definition of this data begins

The actual instructions in the code are irrelevant for my purposes.

I'm anticipating a lot of people saying I should just use a regex for this (or even Flex & Bison), but these aren't really valid, as I do need the preprocessor and template stuff handled properly.

Comment: Even if you expanded the preprocessor and the template directives, regexp won't be strong enough to collect this type information correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [gcc-xml](http://public.kitware.com/GCC_XML/HTML/Index.html) in combination with the c++ xml-library or xml-friendly scripting language of your choice.

Comment: From the description on the page you linked, this sounds like its exactly what I'll need.

Comment: Cool, the faq also says that instantiated templates are also logged, this sounds perfect (only thing it seems to lack is the "function bodies", which is the one thing I really don't need at all)

Comment: Good to hear, i think its convenient for simpler cases.

Comment: So you parse C++, emit XML and than parse XML... I'm impressed. (Hint: rampant sarcasm).

Comment: If you have to much money you can buy front-ends from the Edison Group. If too much time you hack up gcc to give you what you need. Or you implement a complete c++ parser yourself. Have fun with that. (Hint: Irony intended)

Answer (score 4):

Running [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) on the code would give you most of that, wouldn't it?

In what format do you want the output?

Comment: From what I've seen, Doxygen can really only output human friendly data, parsing that might take a bit more for a program, I just need it in a format where I can easily access that info through code.

Answer (score 4):

- [Elsa: The Elkhound-based C/C++ Parser](http://scottmcpeak.com/elkhound/sources/elsa/),
- [clang: a C language family frontend for LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/)/[Clang Static Analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/),
- [ANTLR Parser Generator Grammar List](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/list) (search for C++, there is more than one grammar),
- [OpenC++](http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/openc++.html) (adds reflection capabilities to C++),
- [Stratego XT](http://www.program-transformation.org/Stratego/) (full programs transformation - see [CodeBoost](http://www.program-transformation.org/Stratego/CodeBoost), which for parsing uses OpenC++ just mentioned, for an example application to C++ programs),
- [Parsing C++ at nobugs.org](http://www.nobugs.org/developer/parsingcpp/) (not a parser but interesting bits of information; in particular [Edward D. Willink's "Meta-Compilation for C++" PhD thesis](http://www.computing.surrey.ac.uk/research/dsrg/fog/FogThesis.html) and Mike Dimmick [overview of his attempt to parse C++](http://www.nobugs.org/developer/parsingcpp/mikedimmick.txt)).

See also Ira Baxter here, where he [cites his own product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520734/what-libraries-are-available-for-parsing-c-to-extract-type-information/1535550#1535550).

**Warning:** mind you, only Elsa "..I hear does a fairly good job.." at constructing a symbol table, which according to Ira Baxter is necessary for OP's original intent (see comments to this answer - I quote him because he is an expert in the field).

Comment: Continuing the commentary, note that the OP wanted a simple way to extract some type information and generate some stuff from that. Handling that with complete c++ parsers is way too time consuming and unnecessary, especially as the cost for parser -> xml -> c++ will not be paid at runtime. Apart from that, nice list.

Comment: You underestimate how computationally costly is parsing XML. As Ira Baxter noted (he is an expert in the field) "*You are right; regex can't even come close to this*" and he means (Ira correct me if I'm wrong) that an half-baked solution will not be useful. Parsing C++ is notoriously hard and without fully parsing it I expect wrong/missing results in whatever extraction process at which you submit the code.

Comment: You not only have to parse, but you need to build up the symbol table.  And this is a bitch; the rules for this occupy the bulk of the 600 page reference manual.   ANTLR-based C++ parsers, OpenC++, Stratego, don't do this.  Willink's thesis is mildly interesting but I don't know of anybody that used its results in anger.  Elsa I hear does a fairly good job.  I think Clang says their C++ parser is incomplete at this point.   GCC-XML does a good job if all you want is type data and  you don't mind the tons of XML that it produces.   DMS does this and produces function body information, too.

Comment: ".. 600 page reference manual" obscene! I was not aware of such difficulties in constructing the symbol table of a C++ program. Thanks for the information. Introducing this accidental complexity in a programming language is folly in my (not so humble) opinion.  I know that Clang C++ parser is incomplete, but they seem to progress at a fast pace, so I included it for future reference. Of course I mind the tons of XML that it produces (XML is a problem, not a solution). That's my motivation in suggesting other starting points than GCC-XML.

Comment: Anyway I'm introducing a warning in my original answer about not all of my suggestions being complete for the OP's intent.

Comment: MaD70, we might have a misunderstanding here - for the given points the OP mentioned gccxml should output sufficient information and it can be put to use in a matter of minutes which i doubt will be possible with full C++ front-ends. GCC to XML to custom app might not be the cheapest thing to do - but if its only meant to assist in a build-enviroment or with some simple code generation the computational cost doesn't matter compared to the development time for the perfect tool for the specific job.

Comment: Not misunderstanding, it was simply **my ignorance** : I was not aware that constructing a symbol table for a C++ program is so difficult also. I thought that the greatest difficulties were in parsing. That GCC-XML do this well is a misfortune: XML (and SGML descendants) are an abomination and GCC-XML is another **useful** tool that **forces** to use it.

Comment: @MaD70: XML isn't *that* bad -- I mean, it's not nearly as clean as JSON, but it sure beats e.g. the old binary Word formats...

Answer (score 2):

[Exuberant Ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) will give you most of what you need, it's usually used by editors to provide code navigation.
May choke on some templates though...

Answer (score 2):

The [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) is general purpose program analysis and transformation machinery.  Its [C++ Front End](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CppFrontEnd.html) builds on DMS to provide full featured C++ parsing for a variety of common C++ dialects, can process set of C++ classes simulataneously, and constructs full name/type/access information that you can use any way you want.   Information is tagged as to precise origin file/line/column.  (It includes a full preprocessor).

You are right; regex can't even come close to this.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: an half-baked solution will not be useful; either one parse it in full or wrong/missing results, in whatever extraction process at which one submit the code, is to be expected.

Comment: The meaning of code is pretty fragile, and depends crucially on the meaning of the user symbols.   Minor errors in interpreting this meaning usually ripple into results a few operators downstream that are nonsense.   If you don't parse C++ pretty in excruciating detail, you can't really build any interesting analyzers let alone tools that can change code reliably.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get macros expanded by just running pre-processor (cpp) on the source.
The templates are not that easy since template instantiation happens much later.

Comment: This was one option i had in the back of my mind, but I've recently had some dealings with the preprocessor for 2 completely different providers (one sony, the other MS) and the output they give is actually different from what is used internally (MS MIGHT just be a whitespace error, but it does cause errors that prevent the pre-processed file from being created. Plus, I still need something to pass the code.

Answer (score 0):

Doxygen can also produce a detailed XML by setting an option in the configuration file. It is quite thorough, and very easy to use. From the [doxygen home page](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/starting.html):

> The XML output consists of a
>   structured "dump" of the information
>   gathered by doxygen. Each compound
>   (class/namespace/file/...) has its own
>   XML file and there is also an index
>   file called index.xml.
>
> A file called combine.xslt XSLT script
>   is also generated and can be used to
>   combine all XML files into a single
>   file.
>
> Doxygen also generates two XML schema
>   files index.xsd (for the index file)
>   and compound.xsd (for the compound
>   files). This schema file describes the
>   possible elements, their attributes
>   and how they are structured, i.e. it
>   the describes the grammar of the XML
>   files and can be used for validation
>   or to steer XSLT scripts.
>
> In the addon/doxmlparser directory you
>   can find a parser library for reading
>   the XML output produced by doxygen in
>   an incremental way (see
>   addon/doxmlparser/include/doxmlintf.h
>   for the interface of the library)